# How to authorize a user after login using laravel oauth2 api

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0

I wrote code for login but after login user is not authenticated.It is redirecting to home page i want it to redirect to /app/user and fetch the user details.I don't know where i am getting error..someone help me please.
Below is my code.

In app/Controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    if(Auth::check(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
     $user = Auth::user();///print_r($user);exit;
      $token =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request, $user, $token);
    }
    //$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request, $user, $token){
    //$this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $user, $token);
}
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user, $token) {
    setcookie("oauth_token", $token);
    return redirect('/');
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $token,
    ]);
}

protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request){
    return response()->json([
        'message' => "not found",
    ], 401);
}
```

In app/middlware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
    // if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    //     return redirect('/home');
    // }
    // return $next($request);
    // }
    $token = isset($_COOKIE["oauth_token"])?$_COOKIE["oauth_token"]:"";//print_r($token);exit;
    //$request['token'] = $token;//this is working
    $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer " .$token);//this is working
    $response = $next($request);
    //$response->header('Authorization', "Bearer " .$token);
    return $response;
}
```

In routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user();
    return dd($user);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: Maybe don't `return redirect('/')` in your `authenticated()` method in the controller, if you don't want to redirect home?

Comment: I have tried..but its not working